Selenium click method does not work as it should
Selenium clicks on a link and opens a new window. But at the same time it sometimes closes the initial window though I need it to be open. Looks like it does so when it fails to receive session_id_cookie from the server. Any ideas how I could  bypass the problem. Either wait for the cookie to come or may be there is a special method to keep the initial window open.
target=item.find_element(By.XPATH, "a")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(target).perform()
target.click()


you can either wait for cookie to resolve like you said otherwise, i would try the following :
You can wait for the cookie to resolve as suggested, or alternatively, try the following approach:
1.  Wait until window_handles.count equals.

2.  Once there are two window handles, retrieve them using windows = driver.window_handles.

3.  Then, switch to the second window with driver.switch_to.window(windows[1]).

Hope this helps !

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
